# R - get sum from one column based on categories in another column

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to learn on my own. I have data in csv format with 1,048,575 rows and 73 columns. I am looking at three columns - year, country, aid_amount. I want to get the sum of aid_amount by country for i) all years, and ii) for years 1991-2010. I tried the following to get for all years BUT the result I get is different from when I sort/sum in Excel. What is wrong here. Also, what change should I make for ii) years 1991-2010. Thanks.

```
aiddata <- read.csv("aiddata_research.csv")
sum_by_country <- tapply(aiddata$aid_amount, aiddata$country, sum, na.rm=TRUE) # There are missing data on aid_amount
write.csv(sum_by_country, "sum_by_country.csv")
```

I have also tried:

```
sum_by_country <- aggregate(aid_amount ~ country, data = aiddata, sum) instead of tapply.
```

The first few rows for a few columns look like this:

```
aiddata_id  year    country                  aid_amount
23229017    2004    Bangladesh               685899.2666
14582630    2000    Bilateral, unspecified   15772.77174
28085216    2006    Bilateral, unspecified   38926.82898
28702455    2006    Bilateral, unspecified   12633.85659
29928104    2006    Cambodia                 955412.9884
27783934    2006    Cambodia                 11773.77268
37418683    2008    Guatemala                40150.7331
94726192    2010    Guatemala                151206.3096
```

Comment: You have to also include `year` as the grouping variable for the second question.  Can you show few lines of your data (with few columns including the `year`)?  Regarding the code, it looks okay for the first part.  If you have included some reproducible example, it would have been great.

Comment: As @Akrun said, code looks ok. Does data look ok too? This is when that part of a "reproducible example" becomes most valuable...

Comment: Thanks @akrun and PavoDive. I have added a few rows of data above. The original dataset could be downloaded at http://aiddata.org/aiddata-research-releases. It is the first bullet: • AidData 2.1 "Full" version

Comment: @PavoDive Please see the sample data above and original data in my comment. Thanks.

Comment: Here is what I did in Excel. Filter "country"; Sum "aid_amount" for one particular country I am interested in.  However, now I realize that Excel gave me an error message "File not loaded completely" and "Excel cannot exceed the limit of 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns". I guess there is more data than Excel could handle. However, the sum I got from R was lower than I got from Excel. Therefore, I assumed a problem in my R code.

Comment: @SiriN Have you crosschecked the results on a very small dataset?

Comment: @akrun, I tried it on a smaller dataset and the results seem to be pretty close (last few positions differ - may be due to rounding differences).  I am still not able to figure out the sum by country for YEAR 1991-2010 part. I want a sum for all those years, not by each year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `data.table` for the big dataset. If you want to get the sum of `aid_amount` for each `country` by `year`

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(aiddata), country,year)[, 
         list(aid_amount=sum(aid_amount)), by=list(country, year)]
```

To get the sum of `aid_amount` for each `country`

```
setkey(setDT(aiddata), country)[, 
          list(aid_amount=sum(aid_amount)), by=list(country)]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. Above code will give me the sum by country by year. I want it for a range of years, not by year. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: @SiriN The second one should give you that.

Answer (score 0):

```
yy=aggregate(df$Column1,by=list(df$Column2),FUN=mean)
```

`Column 2- Categories` on which you want to sum.
If you want to know the maximum `value(sum)` among all categories? Use the below code:

```
which.max(yy$x)
```