# Ranking entries in a column based on sums of entries in another column

Tags: r

everyone. I am a beginner in R with a question I can't quite figure out. I've created multiple queries within Stack Overflow to address my question (links to results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624833/r-get-sum-from-one-column-based-on-categories-in-another-column), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993468/cumulative-sum-of-a-column-based-on-the-values-of-another-column-r), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824662/calculate-cumulative-sum-of-one-column-based-on-another-columns-rank)) but none have addressed my issue. On to the problem: I have subset data frame DAV from a larger dataset.

```
> str(DAV)

'data.frame':   994 obs. of  9 variables:

$ MIL.ID     : Factor w/ 18840 levels "","0000151472",..: 7041 9258 10513 5286 5759 5304 5312 5337 5337 5547 ...

$ Name       : Factor w/ 18395 levels "","  Atticus Finch",..: 1226 6754 12103 17234 2317 14034 15747 4542 4542 14819 ...

$ Center     : int  2370 2370 2370 2370 2370 2370 2370 2370 2370 2370 ...

$ Gift.Date  : Factor w/ 339 levels "","01/01/2015",..: 6 6 6 7 10 13 13 13 13 13 ...

 $ Gift.Amount: num  100 47.5 150 41 95 ...

$ Solic.     : Factor w/ 31 levels "","aa","ac","an",..: 20 31 20 29 20 8 28 8 8 8 ...

$ Tender     : Factor w/ 10 levels "","c","ca","cc",..: 3 2 3 5 2 9 3 9 9 9 ...
 $ Account    : Factor w/ 16 levels "","29101-0000",..: 4 4 4 11 2 11 2 11 2 11 ...

$ Restriction: Factor w/ 258 levels "","AAU","ACA",..: 216 59 216 1 137 1 137 1 38 1 ...
```

The two relevant columns for my issue are MIL.ID, which contains a unique ID for a donor, and Gift.Amount, which contains a dollar amount for a single gift the donor gave. A single MIL.ID is often associated with multiple Gift.Amount entries, meaning that donor has given on multiple different occasions for various amounts. Here is what I want to do:

1. I want to separate out the above mentioned columns from the rest of the data frame;
2. I want to sum(Gift.Amount) but only do so for each donor, i.e. I want to create a sum of all gifts for MIL.ID 1234 in the above data.frame; and
3. I want to rank all the MIL.IDs based on the sum Gift.Amount entries associated with their ID.

I apologize for how basic this is, and if it is redundant to a question already asked, but I couldn't find anything.

Edit to address comment:

[shot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWAAN.png)

```
    > print(ranking)
```

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5l9N.png)

I am struggling to get the formatting correct here so I included screen shots

Comment: share your data in a format that others can read in, and show your expected output

Comment: plyr would be a great package to help you here, and it has lots of helpful info if you do a quick web search.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data. Provide a reproducible example by using `dput`. Same with your output. Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: I apologize. Due to HIPAA considerations, I can't dput the files as it would give people's real names. I will review the link and do better to get my question answered. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df <- DAV[, c("MIL.ID", "Gift.Amount")] #extract columns
df <- aggregate(Gift.Amount ~ MIL.ID, df, sum) #sum amounts with same ID
df <- df[ order(df$Gift.Amount,decreasing = TRUE), ] #sort Decreasing
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks for the help as well as your patience with a neophyte, Sotos. It's appreciated.

Comment: Done. Thank you again.